# Why is this error message not popping up in Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, error-handling, try-catch

I have a script that runs on edit basis and its trigger is installable. When it's run, it copies a row into a another file. I would like to have an error message pop up in case that didn't go through for some reason, so that the user knows it requires additional attention.

Right now, the error I see in the executions logs says it's trying to edit a protected range in the destination sheet. I've added this `try...catch` as follows, but nothing pops up.

```
function myfunction(e) {
  try {
    const startRow = 2;
    const targetColumn = 11;
    const ws = "Data"

    //get modified row and column
    const row = e.range.getRow();
    const col = e.range.getColumn();
    const s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    const cellValue = s.getActiveCell().getValue();
    const salesPapeline = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 1).getValue();
    const branch = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 13).getValue();

    if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ws && col === 2 && row >= startRow) {
      const timeStamp = new Date();

      //This checks if the Job/Lead is to be transferred to Branch 2
      if (salesPapeline == "4. Convert" && cellValue == "2. Branch 2"
        && e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 12).getValue() == "TRANSFERRED") {
        const jobTagValue = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 11).getValue();

        let rowData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 1, 1, 12).getValues();
        let newItems = [];
        let jobTag = rowData[0][10];
        let name = rowData[0][3];
        let company = rowData[0][4];
        let clientNotes = rowData[0][7];
        let startDate = rowData[0][9];
        newItems.push(jobTag, '3. Current needs', '', name, '', company, clientNotes, '', '', '', '', '', startDate)
        e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 12).setValue('TRANSFERRED');
        e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 13).setValue('2. Branch 2');

        const salesSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(BRANCH2_FILE_ID);
        const destSheet = salesSheet.getSheetByName('[MGT-use] Recruiting Funnel');

        if (newItems.length > 0) {
          const destRng = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 13);
          destRng.setValues([newItems]);
        } else {
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (e1) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(e1.message);
  }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the trigger setup:
[image]

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Just did, @Rubén! Thank you!

Comment: Please explain ` in case that didn't go through for some reason`

Comment: Hi @Cooper! It says in the execution logs that it is trying to edit a protected range. How to alert the user, though?

Comment: Is it reproducible? Have you tried it in a new sheet with a  new trigger? Could you add a screenshot of your trigger setup?

Comment: Just added the trigger, @TheMaster!

Comment: Did the provided solutions solve your issue?

Comment: Your function need name is `updateSales`. Here it is `myFunction`. Provide [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This checks the range that was written to see if it is blank

I also stuck some debugging flags in there in the event we need to go further into the process.  But I don't really see anything wrong with it except that you could make better use of the event object and reduce execution time.

```
function myfunction(e) {
  e.source.toast('entry');
  try {
    const sh = e.range.getSheet();
    if (sh.getName() == "Data" && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart >= 2) {
      e.source.toast('Flag1');
      const r = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 12).getValues().flat();
      if (r[0] == "4. Convert" && e.value == "2. Branch 2" && r[11] == "TRANSFERRED") {
        e.source.toast('Flag2');
        let newItems = [];
        newItems.push(r[11], '3. Current needs', '', r[3], '', r[4], r[7], '', '', '', '', '', r[9]);
        sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 12).setValue('TRANSFERRED');
        sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 13).setValue('2. Branch 2');
        const ssh = SpreadsheetApp.openById(BRANCH2_FILE_ID);
        const dsh = ssh.getSheetByName('[MGT-use] Recruiting Funnel');
        if (newItems.length > 0) {
          e.source.toast('Flag3');
          const wr = dsh.getLastRow() + 1
          const drg = dsh.getRange(wr, 1, 1, 13);
          drg.setValues([newItems]);
          SpreadsheetApp.flush();
          if(drg.isBlank()) {
            SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("It did not go through");//warns you if the row that you just wrote to is blank.
          }
        } 
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
}
```

If you wish to share some data in a table I wouldn't mind looking at it. You may need to explain how the sheet works as well.

> Note: I do not follow links to other google accounts.

Answer (score 0):

The trigger `onEdit()` handles errors silently. You can see the errors messages (and logs) in Executions section only:

[image]

For debugging, instead of (or along with) `console.log()`, you can use the `spreadsheet.toast()` tool:

- [toast(msg)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toastmsg)

Comment: Hi! Even when the function's trigger is an installable one? I do see the error in the execution log. How to display it to the user?

Comment: Frankly, I'm not sure about installable one. But I believe it's about UI only. The `try/catch` by it self should work.

Comment: One more factor to consider. The account under which this is running is an organizational one and it would only pop up if run by someone from the inside. Thanks a lot for your input.